# Privoxy stripping CSS from Yahoo Mail

Tags: 11.04, privoxy

I'm currently trying to get Privoxy working as a general filtering solution and the majority of its working fine, however there's an issue where with Yahoo Mail it's stripping all the CSS. I've attempted a few things such as { allow-ads } and setting it as fragile, but neither have fixed it, am I missing anything specific?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but I was using Privoxy with Dansguardian to filter content. If this is your setup, too, it is not Privoxy that is at fault, it is Dansguardian. I was thinking Privoxy, too, but a check of Dansguardian showed it was blocking yimg.com for a css.

To `/etc/dansguardian/list/exceptionsitelist` I added:

```
yahoo.com
yimg.com
```

Did a

```
# service dansguardian restart
```

And yahoo mail magically worked.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: BTW, I'm not actually using Ubuntu, but Linux Mint Debian Edition, but it should still work the same.

Comment: Thanks narnie2, I ended up doing the exact same thing in the end. It was just slightly annoying as it only worked for the Yahoo sites, and I found that a *lot* of sites were having the CSS stripped. It's to do in part with the CSS regexp matching, but I've not solved it fully.